# How to calculate median of frames efficient in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, frame, median

I'm using median function (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) in Matlab in order to calculate average value of each pixels from each frame in a video. Here is my code:

```
[a,b,c,d] = size(video);  //take video's dimensions
background=zeros(a,b,c);  //create a matrix for background image
tempR=zeros(1,d);         //create template matrices for each channel
tempG=zeros(1,d);
tempB=zeros(1,d);
for i=1:a    % for each pixel
    for j=1:b
        for(k=1:d)       //for each frame
            tempR(1,k) = video(i,j,1,k); // r channel
            tempG(1,k) = video(i,j,2,k); // g channel
            tempB(1,k) = video(i,j,3,k); // b channel
        end
        background(i,j,1) = median(tempR);  //calculate median value for each channel
        background(i,j,2) = median(tempG);
        background(i,j,3) = median(tempB);
    end
end
```

My question is: Is there a more efficient way to do this? As shown this way is not efficient and for bigger videos it is working so slow. Using for loops for each frame,channel and pixel makes cost. Can i calculate median value in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
background = median( video, 4 ); % median along fourth dim
```

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: It gives me this error: "Error using median (line 28)
First input must be single or double."

Comment: @ozg, then cast to `single`: `background = uint8( median( single( video ), 4 ) );`

Comment: Okay.I really couldn't guess it can be calculated in a one line,thanks for help.

Comment: @ozg - triple nested loop in Matlab is a bad thing... you MUST have extremely good reason to do so.

Comment: @ozg what version of Matlab are you using? From [doc of `median`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) it seems like it should support `int`s as well...

Comment: @Shai - I use the same line of code in one of my applications and I'm curious: is there any way this process could be speeded up even more?

Comment: @AlexB. computing `median` is quite heavey: you need to sort (at least partially) so I don't suppose you can compute `median` much faster... You may consider using `mean` instead, should be a lot faster...

Comment: @Shai - Thanks, I thought so! However I did find one possibility: using a faster implementation of it, written in c++, through mex (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29453-nth-element). But I haven't tried it yet.